# Making a SEO friendly URL for a CMS

Tags: php, codeigniter, seo

I am trying to create a Content Management System using Codeigniter. I have a page where I display a list of article titles. When any user click on any of the article titles it will take the user to the details of that article in a separate page.

I am displaying the article title list using the following code:

```
 <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>article/<?php echo $row['article_id']; ?>">
 <?php echo $row['article_title']; ?></a>
```

When any user click on the above link it takes the article_id and go to the following controller

Controller:

```
function index($id){

   $this->load->model('mod_articles');
    $data['records']=$this->mod_articles->list_articles($id);
    $this->load->view('view_article',$data);
}
```

Model :

```
  function list_articles($id)
    {   
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('article');
        $this->db->where('article_id', $id); 
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->row_array();

    }
```

Now when I display the result, in the browser's address bar the link looks like this-

```
  localhost/cms/article/1         //<< here localhost/cms/ is my base_url
```

According to this [website](http://cmsteachings.com/frienly-urls-good-seo) , an example of good SEO friendly URL is `http://www.mysite.com/joomla-seo-tips` .

Now my question is how to make my URL look like `localhost/cms/article/my-article-title` instead of showing the id of the article at the end of link?

To acheive this should I query for my article titles instead of article ids or there are some better ways to do that?

Please share your ideas on this.

Thanks in Advance :)

### Edit

So, before saving my content should I run following code get the `$article_slug` and then save it?

```
function create_slug($string){
$slug=preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', $string);
return $slug;
}

$article_slug= create_slug('My Name ');   // as you suggested I will create a new column for this
```

Comment: So what if your url look like this ... ?

**localhost/cms/article/1/my-article-title**

Comment: It is also alright, I guess. But how to do it? thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you save the record, give it a URL slug by running `url_title()` on the title (this should be a unique column, make sure to check for duplicate entries when saving).

`url_title("My page title!")` should return something like `my-page-title`, see the [url helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html). I usually run `strtolower` on slugs as well, looks like CI allows caps.

When you query for the content, get it by `slug`, something like:

```
$this->db->where('slug', $this->uri->segment(1))->get('articles');
```

And of course use the `slug` for your links instead of ids.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please check the edited part of my question above. thanks :)

Comment: Yes, before saving to your database you create the slug.

Comment: I don't get why to use `$this->uri->segment(1))`. I think I can find the result by article_slug.. would you please explain?

Comment: I guess I meant `$this->uri->segment(2)`. It depends on your URLs, just use whatever method is appropriate to fetch the slug from the url. You probably want to just use the first argument of your controller's method.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'article' table can include an additional field ('slug' is a popular name for it so in your example maybe 'article_slug') that is used as both a part of the URL and a field to query against.  Typically the CMS will show 'slug' as an editable field but pre-populate it with the value of the page title transformed (typically by lowercasing the title, converting spaces to dashes and cleaning up any URL unfriendly characters like quotes).